# ui-router child state not able to access parent state data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

A child state component in `ui-router` is having issues reading it's parents data. When logging the `$stateParams` it displays the correct information. This data is passed as parameters to the `ui-sref` attribute, which should result in the correct information being displayed to the user, but it isn't.

Here is the items id being logged (depending on which item is clicked on).

[image: Patent id]

Why is the child state `patents.patent` failing to read the data from parent state `patents`?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

    var states = [
        {
            name: 'patents',
            url: '/patents',
            component: 'patents',
            resolve: {
                patents: function(patentsService) {
                    return patentsService.fetchAllPatents();
                }
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'patents.patent',
            url: '/{patentId}',
            component: 'patent',
            resolve: {
                patent: function(patents, $stateParams) {
                    return patents.find(function(patent){
                        return patent.id === $stateParams.patentId;
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    ]

    states.forEach(function(state) {
        $stateProvider.state(state);
    });

}]);
```

---

```
app.service('patentsService', function($http) {

    var service = {

        fetchAllPatents: function() {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/Sprint002b/restpatent/', {cache: true}).then(function(resp){
                    return resp.data
            });

        }
    };

    return service;

});
```

**components**

```
angular.module('myApp').component('patents', {
    bindings: { patents: '<' },
    template: ' <div>' +
                    '<div>' +
                        '<table>' +
                            '<thead>' +
                                '<tr>' +
                                    '<td>Application No. </td>' +
                                    '<td>Client Ref</td>' +
                                    '<td>Cost now</td>' +
                                    '<td>Cost band end</td>' +
                                    '<td>Cost next</td>' +
                                    '<td>Renewal Date</td>' +
                                '</tr>' +
                            '</thead>' +
                            '<tbody>' +
                                '<tr ng-repeat="patent in $ctrl.patents">' +
                                    '<td><a ui-sref="patents.patent({patentId: patent.id})" ng-bind="patent.applicationNumber"></a></td>' +
                                    '<td ng-bind="patent.clientRef"></td>' +
                                    '<td ng-bind="patent.currentRenewalCost">$</td>' +
                                    '<td ng-bind="patent.costBandEndDate"></td>' +
                                    '<td ng-bind="patent.renewalCostNextStage"></td>' +
                                    '<td ng-bind="patent.renewalDueDate"></td>' +
                                '</tr>' +
                            '</tbody>' +
                        '</table>' +
                        '<div ui-view></div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' 
});
```

---

```
angular.module('myApp').component('patent', {
  bindings: { patent: '<' },
  template: '<h3>A patent!</h3>' +

            '<div><p>Name: {{$ctrl.patent.id}}</p></div>' +
            '<div><p>Id: {{$ctrl.patent.applicationNumber}}</p></div>' +
            '<div><p>Company: {{$ctrl.patent.clientRef}}</p></div>' +

            '<button ui-sref="people">Close</button>'
});
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to populate the child state with data, but only the first item within the JSON object.

I changed the data returned within my `resolve` property in my config file. Data is being loaded, but isn't changing when item is selected.

Any ideas on what I should do? This is all working in a plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/jbZgIg?p=preview

```
{
   name: 'patents.patent',
   url: '/{patentId}',
   component: 'patent',
   resolve: {
       patent: function(patents, $stateParams) {
       return patents.find(function(patent){
       return $stateParams; // changed from patent.id === $stateParams.patentId
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was down to using a strict equality operator rather than equal to. So the code is now:

```
{
  name: 'patents.patent',
  url: '/{patentId}',
  component: 'patent',
  resolve: {
    patent: function(patents, $stateParams) {
    return patents.find(function(patent){ 
        return patent.id == $stateParams.patentId; //not === operator
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This may be a problem with `patentId` being a `string` and `patent.id` being a `number`.  If so, you could change your url to `/{patentId:int}` which will parse the parameter as an integer inside `$stateParams`